# How can I make a Widget leave the screen to the right and another one come from the left with AnimatedSwitcher and SlideTransition?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

This is the transition effect I need to give my component
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B6sVt2m42JYC17lK7m7qZzcSUJ4fXVhK/view
I've searched all over but I'm still unable to find a solution that gives this effect. I'd really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try page view

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final PageController controller = PageController();
    return PageView(
      /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
      /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.
      controller: controller,
      children: const <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Text('Third Page'),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Check this link for reference https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html

Comment: I've looked it up and from what I've seen it swipes the whole screen and what I really need is just the text and the two buttons to be transitioned @Kaushik Chandru

Comment: You can use a pageview inside a sized box of a specific height and have rest of the widgets below that page view